# Making exported packages in an OSGI bundle accessible to all applications deployed in JBoss 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, osgi, jboss7.x

I am looking for the correct way to make classes in exported packages in a certain OSGI bundle accessible to all the Java EE applications deployed in JBoss AS 7.
What I have been doing until now as a workaround, is dropping the OSGI bundle jar in the JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments folder, and then per each war where I need access I add in its MANIFEST.MF file this line:
`Dependencies: deployment.<OSGIBundleName>:<OSGIBundleVersion>`.

My question is: Is there a way to publish a OSGI bundle in JBoss (in the 'bundles' folder?) and instruct the application server to make accessible the bundle exported packages to ANY application deployed in it ?

I know that making a package accessible to all the applications in JBoss is possible using modules (https://community.jboss.org/message/604576), but I was wondering if the same can be done with an OSGI bundle instead.

Comment: To an application server, a bundle is just a jar.  The exported packages are meaningless.

Comment: Hi @Robin!, as far as I understood JBoss 7 is OSGI 'aware', so I thought that exporting packages was needed to make accessible only certain packages in the bundle and hiding other ones. Is this not the case ?

Answer (score 0):

Put them in the "bundles" folder?

Comment: only putting the OSGI bundle in the "bundles" folder does not work. I did that but the web applications cannot see classes in the exported packages inside the bundle. I guess I should do something similar to what is explained here for configuring JBoss Global Modules: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-GlobalModules, but I cannot find an equivalent explanation for OSGI bundles.

Comment: The jars in the web application are OSGi bundles themselves? They have a complete OSGi manifest with Bundle-ManifestVersion, Bundle-Name, Bundle-SymbolicName, Bundle-Version, Import-Package, …?

Comment: no, the web application is not an OSGI bundle, neither its internal jars. There is another OSGI bundle that I would like to make available to ALL my web applications deployed in JBoss (I mean, the classes in its exported packages only). This bundle has a complete OSGI manifest, generated by Eclipse. I followed this tutorial to create that OSGI bundle using Eclipse: http://coderthoughts.blogspot.com/2010/11/using-osgi-in-jboss-as7.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is going to work because JBoss is likely to ignore the Export-Packages part of the manifest if it's not it 'OSGi mode' (I'm guessing here though).

If I were you I would split the bundle into an API bundle that exports *all* its classes and an implementation bundle that depends on it. You can treat the API bundle as an ordinary jar since it'll expose the same classes irrespective of whether it's being used in an OSGi context or not.

Comment: Hi @artbristol!, not sure if I understand the first sentence. In which circumstance JBoss is likely to ignore the Export-Packages in an OSGI bundle and when that will not be the case ?. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert on JBoss, but I assume a normal WAR deployment doesn't have any access to OSGi bundles and whatnot, so I'd have thought JBoss would ignore Export-Packages etc. in that case.